# How to extract the digits and multiply it?

Tags: java

I'm halfway through with the Luhn Formula. I just want to do it by my own understanding using my knowledge so I can fully understand how it well executed
But I have a problem in multiplying the reversed string(number) each by 2.

```
String input = "1234567890123456";
    String reverse = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();
    String a = "";
    String c = "";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= reverse.length() - 1; i+=2){
        a += reverse.charAt(i);
        int intValue = Integer.parseInt(a);
        if ( intValue * intValue > 9){

        }
    }


    for (int i = 1; i <= reverse.length() - 1; i+=2){
        c += reverse.charAt(i);
    }
```

a = for the every number in the reverse variable
c = for the remaining number

Comment: Where you are multiplying? You are incrementing by 2.

Comment: I don't know how to extract the variable a to int so I can multiply it by 2 each

Comment: int intValue= Integer.parseInt(a);

Comment: Where should I store the product? I tried this one out please check my updated

Comment: How to i mean separate the two digits? for example (7 + 7 = 14) that should be (1 + 4)